# How to get JSON data from node.js to HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to create a web app with some drop down menus that contain data from a sql server database.  After some searching I figured out how to use node.js to output the table data into the command prompt.

```js
var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
var config = {
  connectionString: 'Driver=SQL Server;Server=NAME\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=true;'
};
sql.connect(config, err => {
  new sql.Request().query('SELECT * FROM TABLE', (err, result) => {
    console.log("Works");
    if(err) { // SQL error, but connection OK.
      console.log("  Error: "+ err);
    } else { // All good.
      console.dir(result);
    };
  });
});
sql.on('error', err => { // Connection bad.
  console.log("Bad");
  console.log("  Error: "+ err);
});
```

Now the problem is I don't know how to get that result into JSON data that can be used in my web app. Any help would be appreciated as I am quite new to node.js.  Thanks!

EDIT:
Thanks for the help so far! I added the following code for when there is no error:

```js
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

JSON.stringify(result);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
      app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.send(result)
      })
```

I also have all of the code for the http server but I don't think it's necessary to show it all. Is this all that is needed on the server side?

Comment: To convert the object to JSON you simply would run `JSON.stringify(result);` on success and `JSON.stringify(err);` on error.  Then you'd basically make a rest endpoint out of this and call it using AJAX from javascript on your frontend app.

Comment: @abc123 Thanks for the help! I wasn't sure what a rest endpoint was so after looking it up, I tried adding it in and edited my post to reflect it.  Is that what you meant? I'm not sure how to call it on the frontend as I don't know what to call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to send data from the server to the client you'll have to run an HTTP server as part of your Node backend. Then, once the web app loads, it should make a request to your server, which as a response will return the data from the database. For more information on how to do this check out [Express](https://expressjs.com/) (for the server side) and [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (for the client side).